# How to do a string replace in a urlencoded string

Tags: python, string

I have a string like `x = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20owner%2Curls%20from%20flickr.photos.info%20where%20photo_id%3D'%s'&format=json"`

If I do `x % 10` that fails as there are `%20f` etc which are being treated as format strings, so I have to do a string conactination. How can I use normal string replacements here.?

Comment: umm. How does this risk sql injection? the only part where this is used would be a urlopen (or family) call, and I am assuming that Yahoo would have escape mechanisms in place. (My point being, this is not the correct place to escape the input, IMO)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

urldecode the string, do the formatting, and then urlencode it again:

```
import urllib

x = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20owner%2Curls%20from%20flickr.photos.info%20where%20photo_id%3D'%s'&format=json"
tmp = urllib.unquote(x)
tmp2 = tmp % (foo, bar)
x = urllib.quote(tmp2)
```

As one commenter noted, doing formatting using arbitrary user-inputted strings as the format specification is historically dangerous, and is certainly a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can use the new-style output formatting (available since v 2.6), which doesn't rely on %:

```
x = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20owner%2Curls%20from%20flickr.photos.info%20where%20photo_id%3D{0}&format=json'
x.format(10)
```

It also has the advance of not being typedependent.

Answer (score 0):

In python string formatting, use `%%` to output a single % character ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)).

```
>>> "%d%%" % 50
'50%'
```

So you could replace all the % with %%, except where you want to substitute during formatting.  But @Conrad Meyer's solution is obviously better in this case.